# SQL delete from a table where a value is true in other table

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I need to write an sql with the below requirements..

1. I have a table A with column AA in it.
2. I have another table B with column BB in it.
3. Column A in table AA will have only two values ..
   either 0 or 100 and column  column BB in table B has only one value either 1 or 2 or 3....or 7 and this value represents the daynumber in a week and so will change daily in order or Monday(value=0) to Sunday(value=7)..Please ignore the content in comments./* BB in table b has values from 1 through 7.*/ 
   There is no column common between A and B tables

Now, I need to delete table A where AA = 100... but  this should happen only when column BB = 7.

Can anyone help me out to write SQL for the above.

Comment: There *has* to be some relation between table A and table B for this to be done procedurally.  Is there a table C that has columns mapping A to B maybe?

Comment: @identifymecnu: Is there any foreign key relationship between these two tables? If yes, then what is that column?

Comment: What you are describing is pretty easy using a WHERE EXISTS clause, but without a linking column between the two tables, how do you know which to delete?   Do you delete all from A where AA=100 if any rows in table B has a 7?   (Again, easy to do, but need more clarity)

Comment: If there's no relationship between the two tables, then what's the point of watching BB for being 7?

Comment: @nybbler: im afraid that there is no such table C

Comment: @nybbler, @Anil: im afraid that there is no such table or foreign key C<br>@Sparky: Yes, I want to delete all from table A where AA=100 when BB is 7...  I also made a correction in the question statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement below will delete all rows from a where aa is equal to 100, only if there exists one or more rows in b where bb is equal to 7.

```
delete from a where aa = 100 and exists (select * from b where bb = 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

See check this if you want like this.

```
create table A (AA int)
create table B (BB int)

insert into A values (100)
insert into B values (1)

--Invalid Case
if exists (select 1 from B where BB = 7)
begin
    delete from A where aa = 100
    if @@rowcount > 0
    begin
        print 'BB in B has value euqal to 7'
    end
end
else
    begin
        print 'BB in B not equals to 7'
    end

--Valid Case
update B set BB = 7
if exists (select 1 from B where BB = 7)
begin
    delete from A where aa = 100
    if @@rowcount > 0
    begin
        print 'BB in B has value euqal to 7'
    end
end
else
    begin
        print 'BB in B not equals to 7 and Data Deleted from A'
    end
```

Comment: I wish i could use this if I can use procedures in my code. Thank you